# how to remove characters using treplace

Tags: talend

I have pulled in a JSON using the `tRest` stage, and some of my values appear like this: `["345"]`.  I need to convert this to a integer: `345`.  I know I need to remove the extra characters, but I'm having the worst luck using `EReplace` and `Integer` in a `tmap`.  I was recommended to use `tReplace`.  Can someone please show me how to set it so I can remove the brackets and quotes?

Just for the record, here is the line that I tried in `tMap`:

```
Integer.parseInt(StringHandling.EREPLACE(StringHandling.EREPLACE(StringHandling.EREPLACE(row2.rank,"[",""),"]",""),"\"",""))
```

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried the built-in JSON components?  tExtractJSONFields for example?  You shouldn't have to manually parse ECMA compliant JSON data in Talend, at least I wouldn't think so.  I have been able to interact with Rest services using the built in components without manual parsing.

Comment: What was the error message with the EREPLACE function you used in tMap ? it should have worked.

Comment: @E LaRoche, I have tExtractJSONFields, but the outputs show the values I explained above.  That means to me that the JSON had extra characters.

Comment: it was giving me a general JAVA parsing error.  I put in the value `["345"]` in the testing value, and attempted this, and it just errored.  That's when i was recommended not to do this in a tmap, but to do it in a treplace.  of note, `345` is also meant to convert into an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `treplace` component, use the code like below in `tMap` component

```
Integer.parseInt(row2.rank.replaceAll("\"","").replaceAll("\\[","").replaceAll("\\]",""));
```

The above will give you the expected result

Hope this would help you out.